# Minesweeper BombCounts

Tags: java, minesweeper

I have a method which checks all of its surrounding squares and returns the number of bombs around it. But it's really long code and ugly, so can it be shorten?

```
final int MINE =10

for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < counts[0].length; y++) {
    if (counts[x][y] != MINE) {
    int Minesearch = 0;
    if (x > 0 && y > 0 && counts[x-1][y-1] == MINE) {//up left
        Minesearch++;
    }
    if (y > 0 && counts[x][y-1] == MINE) {//up
        Minesearch++;
    }
    if (x < counts.length - 1 && y > 0 && counts[x+1][y-1] == MINE) {//up right
        Minesearch++;
    }
    if (x > 0 && counts[x-1][y] == MINE) {//left
        Minesearch++;
    }
    if (x < counts.length - 1 && counts[x+1][y] == MINE) {//right
        Minesearch++;
    }
    if (x > 0 && y < counts[0].length - 1 && counts[x-1][y+1] == MINE) {//down left
        Minesearch++;
    }
    if (y < counts[0].length - 1 && counts[x][y+1] == MINE) {//down
        Minesearch++;
    }
    if (x < counts.length - 1 && y < counts[0].length - 1 && counts[x+1][y+1] == MINE) {//down right
        Minesearch++;
    }
    counts[x][y] = Minesearch;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is ```MINE``` initialized to, or what is its value if it is a constant?

Comment: @bob    final int MINE = 10; This is it.

Comment: It might be helpful to include that info in the question.

Comment: @bob Thanks I'll add MINE initialized

Answer (score 11):

It can be shortened and "beautified" by refactoring the bounds cyhecking and mine checking into internal method:

```
private boolean isWithinBounds(int x, int y) {
    return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height;
}

private boolean isMine(int x, int y) {
    return field[x][y] == MINE;
}
```

Then the mine count becomes trivial (we can assume that the center of the 3x3 square does not have a mine, otherwise the player would have exploded and ended the game):

```
for (int x1 = x - 1; x1 <= x + 1; x1++) {
    for (int y1 = y - 1; y1 <= y + 1; y1++) {
        if (isWithinBounds(x1, y1) && isMine(x1, y1) {
            mineCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

What we have done is breaking code into methods, each of which implement a small and well defined function. Because each method does exactly one thing, they become easier to understand, maintain and test.

You should check [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). Variable names should be in `camelCase`, `startingWithSmallLetter`.

Variable and method names should describe the reason why the code exists. E.g. `mineSearch` is confusing as the variable does not search mines, it just keeps count of them. Thus `mineCount` is a better alternative.

`Counts` is also confusing as it contains a value named `MINE` which obviously is a marker for a cell containing mine but it also contains the surrounding mine counts. I did a minesweeper clone (or actually a minesweeper solver) once and I used an array containing Cell-objects. The Cell object provided methods for querying the status of the cell (stepped on, flagged, unknown) and the number of surrounding mines if it had been stepped on.

Comment: Why `isWithinBounds(-1, -1)` should return `true`? It will make `isMine` fail. The condition should be `x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < mines.length && y < mines[0].length`.

Comment: Good point @Marc. I had the condition exactly backwards!

Comment: Also, I would normally write `x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height`. The same variable together. However, that's a really minor point.

Comment: Why `x1`/`y1`? Also, that does check the current field, too, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Bobby The assumption is that mine count is performed only after the user has stepped on the current field. If there is a mine, the game ends and a mine count is not needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

While the Answer of @TorbenPutkonen is correct it is a *procedural* approach to the problem.

There is nothing wrong with  *procedural* approaches as such, but since Java is a *object oriented* language we might look out for OO-approaches instead...

I would extract the neighbor check into an `enum` like this:

```
enum Direction {
  NORTH{
     boolean isBomb(inx x, int y, boolean[] field){
       if(0 < x)
         return BOMB == field(x-1, y);
       else
         return false;
     }
  },
  NORTH_WEST{
     boolean isBomb(inx x, int y, boolean[] field){
       if(0 < x && 0 < y)
         return BOMB == field(x-1, y-1);
       else
         return false;
     }
  },
  SOUTH{
     boolean isBomb(inx x, int y, boolean[] field){
       if(field.length-1 > x)
         return BOMB == field(x+1, y);
       else
         return false;
     }
  },
  SOUTH_EAST{
     boolean isBomb(inx x, int y, boolean[] field){
       if(field.length-1 > x && field[0].length-1>y)
         return BOMB == field(x+1, y+1);
       else
         return false;
     }
  }
  // other directions following same pattern

  abstract boolean isBomb(inx x, int y, boolean[] field);
}
```

The benefit is that this enum could live in its own file and has a very limited responsibility. That means it is easy to understand what is does, isn't it?

In your calculation method you can simply iterate over the `enum` constants like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < counts[0].length; y++) {
    int mineCount =0;
    for(Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
       if (direction.isBomb(x, y, counts) ) {
            mineCount++;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

---

As a next step I'd apply the "tell, don't ask" principle by changing the method signature:

```
abstract int getBombValueOf(inx x, int y, boolean[] field);
```

the implementation in the `enum` would change like this:

```
     int getBombValueOf(inx x, int y, boolean[] field){
       if(0 < x && BOMB == field(x-1, y))
         return 1;
       else
         return 0;
     },
```

That could be simplified to the "elvis operator":

```
     int getBombValueOf(inx x, int y, boolean[] field){
       return (0 < x && BOMB == field(x-1, y))
         ? 1 
         : 0;
     },
```

and the usage would change to this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < counts[0].length; y++) {
    int mineCount =0;
    for(Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
       mineCount += 
           direction.getBombValueOf(x, y, counts) );
    }
  }
}
```

---

We could achief the same (exept moving the neighbor calculation to another file) by using a `FunctionalInterface` and a simple collection:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Direction{
  int getBombValueOf(inx x, int y, boolean[] field);
}

private final Collection<Direction> directions = new HashSet<>();

// in constructor
   directions.add(new Direction() { // old style anonymous inner class
         int getBombValueOf(inx x, int y, boolean[] field){
           return (0 < x && BOMB == field(x-1, y))
             ? 1 
             : 0;           
         }
    };
   directions.add((x, y, field)-> { // Java8 Lambda 
           return (0 < x && 0 < y &&BOMB == field(x-1, y-1))
             ? 1 
             : 0;
    };
    // more following same pattern

// in your method
    for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < counts[0].length; y++) {
        int mineCount =0;
        for(Direction direction : directions) {
           mineCount += 
               direction.getBombValueOf(x, y, counts) );
        }
      }
    }
```

---

Of cause we could make much more benefit from OO principles if the game field would not be an *array of primitives* but a *Collection of Objects*. But that might be stuff for another answer... ;o)

Comment: Instead of copy-pasting the code in the enums, you could define an xy-offset for each direction and reuse the same code in each value. Personally I don't advocate for adding any functionality to enums. They're intended to be a tool for enumerating value sets and making them a container for code violates that intention and as such, always surprises the user. There are always better ways to implement the functionality.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen `enum`s are *full featured* classes. Classes are used to provide different behavior. So I don't see any reason to use `enum`s as dump constants only, especially if in turn they are used to introduce *branching* by use of a `switch` block. But I agree that the code in the `enum`s could be cleaned a little more... And just vor the records: my second approach does what you suggest.